# Add BCC / CC to Contact Form 7 emails

Tags: wordpress, contacts, contact-form-7

How do I add a CC/BCC to a WordPress using Contact Form 7 using the Contact Form 7 hook?

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'dynamic_addcc' );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you login to your Wordpress admin and click on the Contact icon on the far left, under the dashboard.

Once you've done that if you click on the Contact Form button, and then click on the Mail tab.

Under the mail tab you will see an "Additional headers" box. In the additional headers box, you can enter the CC and BCC e-mail addresses.

Details on this:

https://michael-shore.uk/blog/add-cc-and-bcc-to-a-contact-form-7-form/

Or you could try:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','dynamic_addcc');

function dynamic_addcc($WPCF7_ContactForm){

// Check contact form id.
if (12345 == $WPCF7_ContactForm->id()) {

    $currentformInstance  = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    $contactformsubmition = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ($contactformsubmition) {

        $bcc_email = array('email1@example.com', 'email2@example.com', 'email3@example.com');

        // saparate all emails by comma.
        $cclist = implode(', ',$bcc_email);

        $data = $contactformsubmition->get_posted_data();

        if (empty($data))
            return;

        $mail = $currentformInstance->prop('mail');

        if(!empty($cclist)){
            $mail['additional_headers'] = "Bcc: $cclist";
        }

        // Save the email body
        $currentformInstance->set_properties(array(
            "mail" => $mail
        ));

        // return current cf7 instance
        return $currentformInstance;
    }
}


}
```

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is how, I commented where possible.

```
/**
 * Add Cc & Bcc to all WordPress mails
 * @author: Archie M
 * 
 */
function dynamic_addcc($WPCF7_ContactForm){

    $currentformInstance  = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    $contactformsubmition = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    $form_id = $currentformInstance->id;

    // If you don't want this on every form, use the form ID instead
    if ($contactformsubmition && ($form_id === 100) ) {

        $bcc_email = array('joe.doe@gmail.com');  // CC or BCC

        //separate all emails by comma if more than one
        $cclist = implode(', ',$bcc_email);

        $data = $contactformsubmition->get_posted_data();

        if (empty($data))
            return;

        $mail = $currentformInstance->prop('mail');

        if(!empty($cclist)){
            $mail['additional_headers'] = "Bcc: $cclist";
        }

        // Save the email body
        $currentformInstance->set_properties(array(
            "mail" => $mail
        ));

        // return current cf7 instance
        return $currentformInstance;
    }

}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'dynamic_addcc' );
```